# PHP could not execute query register_new

Tags: php, mysql

I have the `wamp` server running on my laptop and I've got `phpmyadmin` working, and I'm trying to create a website that allows people to register to. But when I go to the `register_new.php` file, I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\db_fns.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0150  138784  {main}( )   ...\register_new.php:0
2   0.0191  172744  register( ) ...\register_new.php:40
3   0.0191  172760  db_connect( )   ...\user_auth_fns.php:10
4   0.0191  173720  mysqli ( )  ...\db_fns.php:4

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\user_auth_fns.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0150  138784  {main}( )   ...\register_new.php:0
2   0.0191  172744  register( ) ...\register_new.php:40
3   0.0860  173952  mysqli_query ( )    ...\user_auth_fns.php:13
```

And I get `Could not execute query` as a warning

And within my `register_new.php` file, I have:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  // include function files for this application
  require_once('require_fns.php');

  //create short variable names
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $passwd=$_POST['passwd'];
  $passwd2=$_POST['passwd2'];
  // start session which may be needed later
  // start it now because it must go before headers
  session_start();
  try   {
    // check forms filled in
    if (!filled_out($_POST)) {
      throw new Exception('You have not filled the form out correctly. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // email address not valid
    if (!valid_email($email)) {
      throw new Exception('That is not a valid email address.  Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // passwords not the same
    if ($passwd != $passwd2) {
      throw new Exception('The passwords you entered do not match. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // check password length is ok
    // ok if username truncates, but passwords will get
    // munged if they are too long.
    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z]{6,12}$/', $passwd)) {
        throw new Exception('Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters inclusive. Please go back and try again.');
    }

    // attempt to register
    // this function can also throw an exception
    register($username, $email, $passwd);
    // register session variable
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;

    // provide link to members page
    do_html_header('Registration successful');
    echo "Welcome " . $_POST["username"];
    echo 'Your registration was successful.';
    do_html_url('member.php', 'Go to members page');

   // end page
   do_html_footer();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
     do_html_header('Warning:');
     echo $e->getMessage();
     do_html_footer();
     exit;
  }
?>
```

**EDIT**

The `register` function is as follows

```
function register($username, $email, $password) {
// register new person with db
// return true or error message

  // connect to db
  $conn = db_connect();

  // check if username is unique
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where username='".$username."'");
  if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception('Could not execute query');
  }

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    throw new Exception('That username is taken - go back and choose another one.');
  }

  // if ok, put in db
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user values
                         ('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");
  if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception('Could not register you in database - please try again later.');
  }

  return true;
}
```

Also, the code I have to connect to the database is

```
<?php

function db_connect() {
   $result = new mysqli('localhost','user','password');
   if (!$result) {
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
   } else {
     return $result;
   }
}

?>
```

I have a schema called `website` and a database on that schema called `user` which has the following

```
create table user (
    username varchar(16) primary key,
    passwd char(40) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null
);
```

**EDIT2**

It's still not working

Comment: Post code of `register()` function too

Comment: @Saty the `register()` function is in there, it's the `register($username, $email, $passwd);` line

Comment: @smithster That's not the code for the register function, that line is simply calling to the function. We need the actual code for the function register()

Comment: @AlanTan I'll edit it into the question

Comment: share your connection code, DB connection is not correct.

Comment: @Rishi I have edited the question

Comment: If you are in local , try with `new mysqli('localhost','root','');`, most people dont change this, and where is your db name as a fourth parameter ?

Comment: @Rishi I've tried that and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: If your user+password combination is not valid, you won't be able to run queries against MySQL, no matter how much you tweak your PHP code.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This happens when I register a new user

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you need a MySQL database user and password, there's a password for user "root" you configured while installing MySQL

Comment: @johannes I have a database called user (as detailed in the question) and its main user is 'root' and it has got a password

Comment: @smithster Still the database tells you "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" which means it doesn't let you in. Wrong username or password provided.

Comment: @johannes I've tried all the usernames and passwords I can think of but I'll keep trying

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html might help. Bu this is no coding question, thus off topic here (dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com might be more relevant and might have similar questions already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within your server login credentials. You're providing the wrong username and password and thus unable to connect to your database.

The default username and login is usually:

```
Username : 'root'

Password : '' // Empty string.
```

Change the login credentials in your db_connect() function.

```
<?php

function db_connect() {
   $result = new mysqli('localhost','root','');
   if (!$result) {
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
   } else {
     return $result;
   }
}

?>
```